# MouseMove event on dynamically created Form Control Label

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, mouseevent

I am trying to dynamically create a shape in VBA, and then assign a mouse event to it, so that if the user moves the mouse over the shape an event will be triggered.

I searched in this forum and elsewhere on the internet, and realized that shapes cannot have events associated. The workaround is to add a from control (like Label) on top and add an event to that.

Since I am dynamically creating the label, I understand that I need to create a custom `Class` and define the label `WithEvents` to trigger the event. I wrote the code below, but am getting the error

> "Object does not source automation events".

Code for Class Definition:

```
'Class name clsEventShape

Public WithEvents evtLabel As Label

Private Sub evtLabel_mousemove()
    MsgBox "Mouse Moved!!"
End Sub
```

Code for generation of shape and label:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Dim Lbl As Label
Dim evtLbl As clsEventShape
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim WS As Worksheet

Public Sub addShape()
    WS = ActiveSheet

    Set Shp = WS.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 100)

    With Shp
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Rnd() * 255, Rnd() * 255, Rnd() * 255)
    End With

    evtLbl = New clsEventShape
    Set evtLbl.evtLabel = WS.Controls.Add("Form.Label.1")
    Set Lbl = evtLbl.evtLabel

    With Lbl
        .Left = 10
        .Top = 10
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 100
        .Caption = "Hello"
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - Excel Labels don't have event sinks. `Worksheet` also doesn't have a `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The mousemove-event has parameters:

  ```
  Public WithEvents evtLabel As msforms.Label

  Private Sub evtLabel_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
   MsgBox "Mouse Moved!!"
  End Sub
  ```

slightly changed code in your module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Dim Lbl As OLEObject
Dim evtLbl As clsEventShape
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim WS As Worksheet

    Public Sub addShape()
  Set WS = ActiveSheet

    Set Shp = WS.Shapes.addShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 100)

    With Shp
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Rnd() * 255, Rnd() * 255, Rnd() * 255)
    End With

    Set evtLbl = New clsEventShape
    Set Lbl = WS.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    Set evtLbl.evtLabel = Lbl.Object
    With Lbl
        .Left = 10
        .Top = 10
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 100
        .Object.Caption = "Hello"
        .Object.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent 'added
     End With
    WS.Shapes(Lbl.Name).Fill.Transparency = 1 'added
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am getting a compile error when I am doing this - it says "User Defined Type not Defined" in the Class Definition of Public WithEvents evtLabel As msforms.Label


C

Comment: Never mind - it seems to be working now. Not sure what mistake I was making but when I saved and re-opened, it started working. Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: I am trying to make the label transparent but am not able to. I tried BackStyle=fmBackStyleTransparent but it still stays as White and Opaque. My entire logic is based on using a transparent label to which I can attach a MouseMove event. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Added two lines in above code to (help it) make it transparent

Comment: Thanks EvR. I'm getting an error 'Unable to get ADD property of OLEObjects Class' when I run the code. This is breaking on the line Set Lbl = WS.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Label.1"). Can you please advise? I'm not sure why this should not work. Just to add, I am running the code on a MacBook and using Office 2016 for Mac - not sure if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Does adding an (empty) userform to your project work? (From that moment, there's a reference to the MS Forms Object Library) If not I think it's better to start a new thread. The code above works flawless at my computer, (Windows Office 2016)