# VBA UserForm_Initialize merge with hover efect

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a UserForm1, there have UserForm_Initialize, where I define all label properties see below. I also have a code where I can implement hover efeckt see code 2. block.

**UserForm_Initialize code:**

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

'.... my code

    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim index As Integer
    
    index = 1 ' Startindex für die Labels
    
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.label Then 'And ctrl.Tag = "LabelAlignmentTheme" Then
            Dim label As MSForms.label
            Set label = ctrl
            Set label.Picture = UserForm1.GIF.Picture 'read the picture from the picture control
            label.PicturePosition = fmPicturePositionLeftCenter

        End If
    Next
    
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
                With ctrl
                    .FontSize = 10
                    .FontName = "Calibri"
                    .ForeColor = &H464646    '(Dark Gray)
                    .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)  '(weiß)
                    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
                    .BorderColor = &HA9A9A9    '(Light Gray)
                    .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
                    If .Name = "LabelNoData" Then
                        .ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        .FontBold = True 
                        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
                        .FontSize = 12
                        .BackColor = &H8000000F 
                        .Visible = False
                    End If
                End With
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

**Hover efeckt code:**

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If active = False Then
        Label1.BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 229) 'blue green
        active = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If active = True Then
        Label1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiß
        active = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**What did I try and what were I expecting?:**

I tried to merge the two codes, means, all created buttons should also have hover efeckt, but after trying I couldn't do it.

Merged code:

```
Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

'.... my code

    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim index As Integer
    
    index = 1 ' Startindex für die Labels
    
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.label Then 'And ctrl.Tag = "LabelAlignmentTheme" Then
            Dim label As MSForms.label
            Set label = ctrl
            Set label.Picture = UserForm1.GIF.Picture 'read the picture from the picture control
            label.PicturePosition = fmPicturePositionLeftCenter

        End If
    Next
    
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
                With ctrl
                    .FontSize = 10
                    .FontName = "Calibri"
                    .ForeColor = &H464646    '(Dark Gray)
                    .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)  '(weiß)
                    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
                    .BorderColor = &HA9A9A9    '(Light Gray)
                    .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
                    UserForm_MouseMove 'here for merge
                    Label_MouseMove 'here for merge
                    If .Name = "LabelNoData" Then
                        .ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        .FontBold = True 
                        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
                        .FontSize = 12
                        .BackColor = &H8000000F 
                        .Visible = False
                    End If
                End With
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

mouse over:

```
Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Not activeLabel Is Nothing Then
        activeLabel.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiß
        Set activeLabel = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "Label" Then
        If Not activeLabel Is Nothing Then
            activeLabel.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiß
        End If
        Set activeLabel = Me.ActiveControl
        activeLabel.BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 229) 'blue green
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *but after trying I couldn't do it* what do you mean by this? Why could you not do it? Was there an error message that is relevant here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536979/478884 shows how to use a class to capture the mousemove event.

Comment: edited my code, how i tried to merge.
Tim Williams, ill try it now

Comment: Tim Wiliams didnt work realy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

clsLblEvent:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents lbl As MSForms.Label
Private HoverOn As Variant 'current state

Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    HoverFormat True
End Sub

Sub HoverFormat(bOn As Boolean)
    'setting is changed, or first time being set
    If bOn <> HoverOn Or IsEmpty(HoverOn) Then
        lbl.BackColor = IIf(bOn, RGB(204, 255, 229), vbWhite)
        HoverOn = bOn
    End If
End Sub
```

Userform:

```
Option Explicit

Dim col As Collection 'stores instances of `clsLblEvent`

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim ctrl As Object
    Set col = New Collection
    
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'use `Me`
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            '...
            'do your formatting...
            '...
        
        
            col.Add getEventObject(ctrl) 'initialize event capture
        End If
    Next ctrl
    
End Sub

'return an instance of clsLblEvent
Function getEventObject(lbl As MSForms.Label) As clsLblEvent
    Set getEventObject = New clsLblEvent
    Set getEventObject.lbl = lbl
    getEventObject.HoverFormat False 'hover off
End Function


Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim obj
    For Each obj In col 'set all labels' hover format to off
        obj.HoverFormat False
    Next obj
End Sub
```